# delete data from table with no primary key using EF database first

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working on EF database first application and I have encounter the situation where delete records from a table which has no primary key.

I have no control over the database and it is not possible to add any key for the DB table.

What is the best approach I can take?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is ,you need add a primary key.

Why EF need you add a PK? 
Because, PK is a only way to identity the row in the table , if not exists a PK , the table may have many same rows(if have PK,it's different,PK is unique,each row will be different),so if your want to delete or update ,which row is your target? if not exists PK ,EF couldn't know how to identity the row ,so you must have PK in the table.

If you can't add one (may be the DB is from customer, you don't have permission), you can change the mapping XML file between EF and DB,To add a relate PK Element for a unique table column.